# webpack config error of cannot resolve module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

When I run webpack --watch I got error of `Cannot resolve module 'js/app.js'`. And then my app.min.js did not complied when I do `npm run dev`.

I've created a [git repo](https://github.com/eldyvoon/react-webpack-babel-starter-) and this is my webpack.config.js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "js/app.js", //what's wrong with this line?
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "src",
    filename: "app.min.js" //this is not even complied?
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: `entry: "./src/js/app.js",`

Comment: @seti ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./src/js/app.js in /Users/myname/Documents/react-webpack-babel-starter/src

Comment: @seti any clue?

Answer (score 1):

When using `context`, [the `entry` path should start with a `./`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/Configuration#user-content-configuration-object-content) followed by the relative path to the entry file.

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/app.js",
  ...
}
```

Another way to resolve this is without using the `context` key and having an absolute path in the `entry` key like so:

```
entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js')
```

Comment: Don't forget to install the `babel-core` npm module (`npm i -D babel-core`) or you will get the error `ERROR in Cannot find module 'babel-core' @ multi main`. Seems like you are missing it as a dependency in your [package.json](https://github.com/eldyvoon/react-webpack-babel-starter/blob/master/package.json) file.

Comment: Why babel core is needed?

Comment: This solved the first problem, my app.min.js is not produced still.

Comment: `babel-core` is the babel compiler itself, it’s what facilitates running your code through a series of transforms you define. It was previously bundled within a single package with `babel-cli`.

Comment: I followed a tutorial on youtube and this is the author's package.json, https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-core/package.json he did not use babel-core, are you sure babel core still needed?

Comment: Your output path in your `webpack.config.js` needs to be changed to `path.join(__dirname, "src")` as well. Your last link is actually the `babel-core` package.json file so there can't exists a `babel-core` entry, it can't depend on itself.

Comment: Can't I use path.join(__dirname, "src/js")? because I want to put within js. I didn't see it get generated though. Hmm..

Comment: What's the error now? It's working good [here](http://imgur.com/a/1VjbK).

Comment: it's working but there's no app.min.js been generated, but I figured it out, I have to run webpack -p first, which i don't know why.